# Column of Text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in my spreadsheet in which each cell is either a YES or a NO.  I'd like to produce a NO result even if there is only one NO in the column.  I tried

> =IF(C4+"NO","NO","YES").

This works, however I can't figure out how to do a range of the whole column

> - C4:C23

does not work.

Comment: This is a basic excel answer but you copy and paste that formula into the remain cells in the column.  The "C4" element will change relatively.  If you had a cell reference that you wanted to remain constant (not change relatively) you would express it as $C$4 indicating that neither the C or 4 are allowed to change as the formula is pasted.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("YES", C4:C23,1,FALSE)),"NO","YES")
```

You must use ISNA function to retrieve #N/A value in C4:C23 range if YES not exists (so if your column is formed by NO and YES, if YES = 0 so you have only NO) you'll get NO otherwise YES

Comment: This is much more efficient, OP replace `;` with `,` if your regional settings don't work with this.

Comment: @Raystafarian: Hi, yes. I've translated my formula by italian. So if in english you must use , instead of ; you can edit my answer. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the column is C and the first data is in C4, then in D4 put:

```
 =IF(C4="NO",FALSE,TRUE)
```

Copy the formula to D5, D6....D23

In this way we are "converting" NO to FALSE and YES to TRUE, so we can use logic functions.

In D24 put:

```
 =IF(AND(D4:D23)=FALSE,"NO","YES")
```

If you have at least one FALSE in the range D4:D23 it will give the result `NO`, otherwise it will be `YES`.